# How to share in-app videos like Tik-Tok which first download the selected video and after that share it?

Tags: video, download, share

I want to download the video first and then share it to whatsapp or any other platform. As the user clicks share button, the download progress bar appears on screen and as the video gets downloaded then user shares the video on whatsapp.

Comment: Do you have something to save/download (video bytes)? Find out if your programming language allows the saving of file bytes. Find out how WhatsApp expects a file to be shared within their system.

Comment: In addition the good pints above it is worth considering do you really want to download and then share the video, rather than simply share the link to the original video.

Comment: @Mick Can you help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971366/found-drawable-required-int-i-am-trying-to-load-image-in-gravityview-by-glid